# How can I upload / view HTML5 animations in confluence

Tags: html, flash, confluence

Currently we are posting .swf animation (interactive) on our confluence. We just upload them as attachement to a pag and use {multimedia:name=animation.swf } to display them. But we want to make it usable for apple owners and are switching to making these interactive animations in HTML5 in stead of .swf.

But generating the same animation in HTML5 in stead of .swf gives use in stead of  1 swf file a couple of directories with css, javascript, images and html files.

How can I upload these to confluence and display the animation on a page in confluence?

Answer (score 0):

It might matter which version of confluence you're working on.

To use the javascript and css you need, you can go to edit -> Administration -> Edit Layout and edit the space-wide css and js in the appropriate tabs.

As for html, you can use the {html} tags to include html code on your confluence pages like this:

```
{html}<p>Insert your html here</p>{html}
```

Do you know which version of confluence you have?

You might also want to look into the gliffy add-on for confluence. I believe it has the capability to accomplish what you want.

http://www.gliffy.com/products/confluence-plugin/

Comment: Problem is that I don't want users to have to upload x files and edit x html macros to be able to put an html5 animation on confluence.

Comment: How can I achieve it with gliffy? My understanding is that the latest version of gliffy produces html5. But how can I import HTML5 or .swf into a gliffy?

Comment: Well you wouldn't have to constantly be uploading js and css files. You would just specify the js and css once in the confluence layout editor, no upload involved, and then the users would just have to input the html on whatever confluence pages they work on.

Comment: As for gliffy, I don't really know what its capability is with html5 animations as I haven't used it myself. All I can say is that you might need it or another add-on depending on how easy you want the work to be for your users.